# TFS Best Practices Analyzer (BPA) shows missing permission errors although those permissions do exist

Tags: configuration, sharepoint-2010

We've got a TFS 2010 set-up with Sharepoint and Reporting Services. As we recently ran into some problems (charts not showing up on the Sharepoint pages) we decided to use the Best Practices Analyzer to find out whether something in the configuration is messed up. The resulting report shows 235 cricital issues that are all exactly the same:

> "The directory on SomeComputerName referenced by "\SomeComputerName\C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\layouts" does not have correct permissions assigned to the Users group. At a minimum, the Users group needs "ReadAndExecute" permissions."

Now checking the (effective) NTFS permissions for that directory and group shows that everything is as it should be, so I don't know why I get those error messages.

There seem to be (a few) other people with the same problem, but I couldn't find out whether this is a bug in the BPA or whether something else is wrong. Does anyone else have a solution or suggestions?

Thanks in advance

G.